# Multiple filters list in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I would need some help to filter a list of objects in a multiple way. Let me explain, I have this list:

```
List<myObj> obj = [
    myObj(name: "Name 1", team: "Team 1", league: "League 1"),
    myObj(name: "Name 2", team: "Team 1", league: "League 1"),
    myObj(name: "Name 3", team: "Team 2", league: "League 1"),
    myObj(name: "Name 4", team: "Team 2", league: "League 1"),
    myObj(name: "Name 5", team: "Team 2", league: "League 1"),
    myObj(name: "Name 6", team: "Team 3", league: "League 2"),
    myObj(name: "Name 7", team: "Team 4", league: "League 2"),
    myObj(name: "Name 8", team: "Team 4", league: "League 2"),
    myObj(name: "Name 9", team: "Team 5", league: "League 2"),
    myObj(name: "Name 10", team: "Team 6", league: "League 3"),
    myObj(name: "Name 11", team: "Team 6", league: "League 3"),
    myObj(name: "Name 12", team: "Team 6", league: "League 3"),
    myObj(name: "Name 13", team: "Team 7", league: "League 3"),
    myObj(name: "Name 14", team: "Team 7", league: "League 3"),
]
```

On another page I have the possibility to choose multiple filters, for example, I choose to see all the players of League 2 and League 3 and at the same time of Team 6 and and Team 4. so they return these two arrays to me

```
List<String> filtersLeague = ["League 2", "League 3"];
List<String> filtersTeams = ["Team 6", "Team 4"];
```

how do i filter this with these two arrays? thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is like so.

```
List<myObj> filteredList = obj
      .where((e) => filtersTeams.contains(e.team) && filtersLeague.contains(e.league))
      .toList();
```